# Using Ampere's Law without Right-Hand-Rule to derive an expression for the magnetic field around a current

Tags: magnetic-fields, symmetry, electric-current, classical-electrodynamics

I'm a little confused over the textbook example of applying Amperians to get the magnetic field around a current.

I understand we take a loop which shares the rotational symmetry of the wire (a circle centered around the wire) and exploit this symmetry to write:
$$ \oint \tilde{B} \cdot \tilde{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}}$$
as:
$$ \tilde{B} \cdot \hat {\mathcal{L}} \oint \mathrm{d} \mathcal{L}$$
since the component of $B$ in $L$ must be constant around the loop, else our symmetry is broken.

We can rewrite this (for clarity) as:
$$ | \tilde{B}| \cos(\theta) \mathcal{L} $$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the magnetic field and tangent at/to a point on our loop, which is constant across our loop, and $\mathcal{L}$ is the length of our loop.

However, I'm currently clutching at straws as to how we can possibly infer the nature of the magnetic field from this expression, given
$$ \mu_0 I = | \tilde{B}| \cos(\theta) \mathcal{L} $$
To solve this surely requires knowledge of $\theta$, which is knowledge of the orientation of the magnetic field before we even apply our analysis. I understand that $\theta$ is not $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (or any other angle suggesting the field and differential vector are orthogonal) because that would suggest a zero current, which is inconsistent with our system.

At this point, all the examples I've seem invoke the "right hand corkscrew rule" or merely state the magnetic field is circumferential, but that's cheating! Right?

Is there any way I can reason that the magnetic field is circumferential without using this rule, by exploiting more symmetries or Maxwell's equations or even invoking an underlying theory of the right hand corkscrew rule? It feels so sloppy to suddenly introduce knowledge of the magnetic field direction in an attempt to ascertain that field in the first place.

Thanks!

EDIT:

On a slightly related note, when $I = 0$, we conclude $\tilde{B} \cdot \hat {\mathcal{L}} = 0$ suggesting either $\tilde{B} = \tilde{0}$ or $\tilde{B} \perp \hat{\mathcal{L}} $. Assuming the latter case, we can rotate our arbitrary loop to form a closed sphere with a non-zero B field divergence, violating $\nabla \cdot \tilde{B} = 0$, and thus we conclude $\tilde{B} = \tilde{0}$ is the correct case.

Is this reasoning sound / correct (particularly the conversion of our closed loop to a closed surface)?

Can this offer any insight into the problem of a non-zero current?

EDIT:

With the assistance of a white-board, it's finally solved!
[image]

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer once one is acceptable. If you've answered your own question, it would be courteous to write it here and select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'll write up the full solution if I get time and accept it, otherwise I'm happy to accept any other full solution

Comment: Could you comment on what you would say is missing from the solution I posted?

Comment: It doesn't demonstrate the magnetic field parallel to the current is zero. You can't let B perp encapsulate both radial and 'parallel' fields because the 2D divergence theorem used in your full calculation only applies in the plane of the 2D loop. That is, your constructed vector n is parallel to B perp, but is orthogonal to B parallel. Thus, you've concluded the radial B is zero, but the 'parallel' (to current) B drops out in the div theorem and is left ambiguous.

I've tried to clarify it here: http://i.imgur.com/WFnOGrc.png
Essentially, the 2D div theorem sheds no information of B para I.

Comment: Ok, I added a section on why the part of $B$ parallel to the wire is zero (same argument as on your white board).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because magnetic field has zero divergence combined with the symmetry of the problem.

At each point on our Ampere's loop we define three orthogonal unit vectors: $\hat{t}$ which is tangential to the loop, $\hat{r}$ which points radially outward from the center of the loop, and $\hat{z}$ which is parallel to the wire. Using these direction, we write the $B$ field as

$$\vec{B} = B_t \hat{t} + B_r \hat{r} + B_z \hat{z}.$$

Note that as we go around the loop the direction element $d\vec{L}$ is perpendicular to $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{z}$, but parallel to $\hat{t}$:

$$
\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{L} = 0 \qquad
\vec{z}\cdot d\vec{L} = 0 \qquad
\vec{t}\cdot d\vec{L} = L.
$$

Also, due to the rotational and translational symmetry of the problem, the values of $B_t$, $B_r$, and $B_z$ are *constant around any loop of radius $R$ centered on the axis of the wire*.

Writing out the Ampere's law integral with the loop $C$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_0 I  &= \int_C \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{L} \\
&=
B_t \int_C \hat{t} \cdot d\vec{L} +
B_r \int_C \hat{r} \cdot d\vec{L} +
B_z \int_C \hat{z} \cdot d\vec{L} \\
&=
B_t 2\pi R.
\end{align}
$$
Where $R$ is the radius of the loop.
This unambiguously solves for $B_t$.
However, as you pointed out, we have *not* shown that $B_r=0$ and $B_z=0$.

## Prove $B_r=0$

Consider a surface $S$ bounded by a contour $C$.
Let $\hat{n}$ denote the outward pointing normal vector at each point on $C$.
There is an integral theorem which says
$$\int_C (\vec{V}\cdot \hat{n}) dL = \int_S (\nabla\cdot \vec{V})dA . \qquad (\text{divergence theorem})$$

We apply this theorem to our physics problem.
Let the Ampere's loop by the contour $C$ and let the flat disk whose boundary is $C$ be the surface $S$.
In this case, the outward pointing normal vector $\hat{n}$ is just the radial vector $\hat{r}$.
Therefore, the divergence theorem gives

$$
\begin{align}
\int_C (\vec{B} \cdot \hat{r})\,dL &= \int_S \underbrace{ (\nabla \cdot \vec{B})}_{0\text{ by Maxwell's equations}} \,dA \\
B_r \int_C dL &= 0 \\ 
B_r &= 0 .
\end{align}
$$

Since we already said that $B_r$ is constant on the loop, this proves that $B_r = 0$ everywhere (our loop has arbitrary radius so we've now shown that at any radius from the wire $B_r$ is identically zero).

## Prove $B_z = 0$

[image]

We now construct a new loop, as shown in the attached diagram.
There is not current enclosed by this loop, so we have

$$
B_r \int_C \vec{r}\cdot d\vec{L} +
B_t \int_C \vec{t}\cdot d\vec{L} +
B_z \int_C \vec{z}\cdot d\vec{L}
= 0 . \qquad (*)$$

The loop lies entirely in the $r-z$ plane.
Therefore, the length element $d\vec{L}$ has no component in the $\hat{t}$ direction.
Combining this with the fact that we already showed $B_r=0$, we simplify $(*)$ to

$$B_z \int_C \vec{z} \cdot d\vec{L} = 0. $$

The side segments (blue) of our loop have no component in the $\hat{z}$ direction.
We can take the dotted segment to be arbitrarily far away where the $B$ field must go to zero.
Therefore, the only remaining segment contributing to the integral is the red segment.
The red segment is entirely in the $\hat{z}$ direction: $d\vec{L} = \hat{z}dL$.
This leaves us with
$$
\begin{align}
B_z \int_{\text{red segment}} (\hat{z} \cdot \hat{z}) dL &= 0 \\
B_z \times (\text{length of red segment}) &= 0 \\
B_z &= 0 .
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh, so the zero-divergence of the B field must be respected in not just 3D, but also in 2D (and the zero-divergence says there can be absolutely no 'outward radial' component of B at all, it must be absolutely zero)?

Comment: Zero divergence doesn't generally say that the radial component is zero everywhere. It says that the *integral of the radial component around a contour* is zero. It's only because of the circular symmetry of the problem that this turns out to imply that the radial component actually is zero everywhere. Does that make sense?

Comment: By the way, this was a really good question. I had to think about this for a while and it made me realize that I had been hoodwinked as a high schooler :)

Comment: I think so. So div(B) = 0 says the total "flux" through the loop is absolutely zero? I've just never seen div(B) = 0 applied to a loop, only closed surfaces. I guess I can't contrive a valid 3D analytic B field that results in a 2D loop having a net* non-zero radial component (at least, not immediately). But let me try!

Comment: What about this horrible looking tree looking field? http://i61.tinypic.com/t8ufpx.png We could make the field have such a geometry that the net magnetic flux through a sphere enclosing it is zero, but we can see that since the field diverges radially upward, we can draw a loop around it with a non-zero net radial component. Doesn't this suggest a non-zero divergence of the magnetic field in/around that loop? (And isn't this a legal / conceivable field?)

Comment: @AntiEarth: You are right that the divergence considerations really apply in 3D with closed surfaces. However, because of the symmetry of the wire problem, the B field can't have any component parallel to the wire. That's why you analyze that problem in a 2D plane with the wire pointing out of the plane. As for your example, that field can't possible be the solution for the current-carrying wire, because it doesn't respect the symmetries of the problem. It's great that you're thinking this way, though. Don't take my word for anything. Check everything for yourself and you'll do really well.

Comment: For the weird tree example, the rotational symmetry was still there though, wasn't it? (about the axis of the "tree"). I was just trying to wrap my head around the integral of a B field perpendicular to the loop around the loop being zero, since it's 2D. However, I've only just now realized that invoked integral theorem proves exactly that, accepting the divergence at any point is zero.
Do you know exactly which theorem that is? (Is it Stoke's combined with a bit of curl manipulation?)

Thanks heaps! :)

Comment: (oh! I've also realized we can exploit the translational symmetry of the wire to turn our loop into a cylindrical closed* surface which then must definitely have a zero 'net' radial B component)

Comment: @AntiEarth: Yes, the translational symmetry is the key here. As for which theorem says $\int_S (\vec{W}\cdot \hat{n})dA = \int_{\text{Vol}}(\nabla \cdot \vec{W})dV$, it's probably called the "divergence theorem". It's also called "Gauss's law" when applied to electric field and charge. In the end, *all* of these vector calculus theorems are various incarnations of the N-dimensional Stokes's theorem, which is a truly amazing and beautiful bit of math.

Comment: @AntiEarth: And yeah, you should imagine a cylindrical 3D surface in the wire problem. The translational symmetry tells you there isn't any $B$ field along the axis of the wire, so no $B$ field pierces the "caps" of the cylinder. The translational symmetry also tells you that the $B$ field looks the same at each slice through the cylinder. This is why, in the end, you just have to consider a circle enclosing the wire. Does this make sense?

Comment: Actually, I've become rather unsatisfied mulling over this. In this cylindrical example, by the translational symmetries, we can apply Gauss' law for magnetism to show there's no radial magnetic field. However, for a contrived system without that translational symmetry (just rotational), it's obvious that if the integral of radial magnetic field is zero, so too is the field (by the symmetry). As to why the integral would be zero, alludes me in every possible way. The orthogonality between the differential loop vector and the proposed field seems to halt everything! :c

Comment: in fact, even with the translational symmetry in this scenario, how can we be sure there is no component of the magnetic field parallel to the axis of the wire/cylinder? All our Amperian loop informs us is the magnitude of the "circumferential" magnetic field, but sheds no information on the two directions orthogonal to the circumference tangent (although we eliminate the radial component by the translational symmetry and Gauss' law of magnetism).

Having thoroughly confused myself, I offer another picture! http://i58.tinypic.com/259ixww.png

Comment: blehhhhhhhhh, forgive me. For this situation, we can show the magnetic field tangent to the cylinder axis is zero, by taking the integral of an amperian loop around empty space (eg: a rectangle with lengths parallel to the axis and widths curved circularly around the wire, since we know B circumferentially already). My mind is a mess

Comment: Start over. Approach the problem from absolutely step 1. Each time you write down an equation, ask yourself what the assumptions are, and refuse to move forward until you understand what you're doing. You'll get it. I can chat with you about this later if you want. I'm on Pacific time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17296/discussion-between-anti-earth-and-danielsank).